# How see if array contains object without using JQuery

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var myArray = [
  {'id' : 1, 'name' : 'test1'},
  {'id' : 2, 'name' : 'test2'},
  {'id' : 3, 'name' : 'test3'}
];
```

Then I have a variable that contains some id:

v`ar someId = 2;`

How can I check if `myArray` contains an `Object`, who's id is equal to `someId`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Do you just want to know it is there or do you want the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `.some()` method:

```
var isThere = myArray.some(function(element) {
  return element.id == someId;
});
```

The [`.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns a boolean `true` if the callback returns `true` for some element. The iteration stops as soon as that happens.

If you want the element in the array and not just a yes/no answer, you can pass the same kind of callback to `.find()`:

```
var theElement = myArray.find(function(element) {
  return element.id == someId;
});
```

When that callback returns `true`, the iteration stops and `.find()` returns the element itself. If none is found, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: So much nicer than a `for` loop or `filter` etc, EDIT: Note `.find()` has no IE support according to MDN.

Comment: For those supporting IE 8, `.some()` is not supported. It is IE 9+.

Comment: @JohnWasham true - [MDN has a polyfill for old browsers though.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
var filteredArray = myArray.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id == someId

});

if(filteredArray.length > 0) {
   console.log("Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS:

```
var myArray = [
  {'id' : 1, 'name' : 'test1'},
  {'id' : 2, 'name' : 'test2'},
  {'id' : 3, 'name' : 'test3'}
];

function findby(arr, key, val){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
       if(arr[i][key] === val){
           return arr[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var found = findby(myArray, "id", 2);
alert(found.name);
```